# How to figure out whether testing is +ve or -ve if some unexpected even occur after registration of a Device

Tags: testing

The question is related to positive/Negative testing. 
Requirement: Apply for Discount button will be visible to user if registration of device takes palce till 31st August. 
Test Scenario: Now if user Registers the device on 1st september and after registration even on 1st September the Apply for Discount button gets displayed.

Is this a Positive testing or Negative testing? Please clear my doubts.

Answer (score -1):

Both answers are correct, Can be +ve or -ve testing